# Android System Call for system date format returning null

Tags: android

I am trying to get the user defined System Date Format by calling `Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.DATE_FORMAT))`.  Upon logging the result, it appears I am being returned null.  I tried calling this method from a class that extends application as well as the first activity that runs when my application starts.  Any ideas?... Is there another recommended method to grab the date format of the system?

Comment: Android does not care from where you call that method, it does not even know. Values being null typically means they are not set. Are you sure there is a custom date format set in your device? What about http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html (Note: NOT `java.text.DateFormat`)? That provides dateformats too.

Comment: the method getContentResolver() requires a context to be based off.

Comment: Whatever has a `getContentResolver()` method is a `Context`, just pass `this` in.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but better late than never...
I encountered the same issue using that method, which returns null. I swear it used to work once, and maybe it became broken in some update. However, you can use a different method: `android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormatOrder(context);` which returns a `char` array containing `'d'`,`'m'` and `'y'` chars in the order specified by the system date format. So that if the format is **"31/12/2014"** the array will be:

```
char[0] = 'd';
char[1] = 'm';
char[2] = 'y';
```